# How can I programmatically authenticate a user in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

How can I log-in the user programmatically in Django? I have the username and password of the User. Is there a method that let's me log him in?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is no other way than "programmatically". Of course, this is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in).

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
```

Comment: Re your revision comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) recommends omitting spaces around `=` in keyword arguments, but of course you're free to do whatever you want.

Comment: @icktoofay I'm well aware of what PEP 8 recommends. (It's not a good recommendation)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus You really think its a bad recommendation?  Thats odd of you.

Comment: @jdg do you have a substantial argument, or did I miss the memo about how we are now supposed to qualify users instead of posts on SO? :/

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I think it would impair readability to people who are used to using spaces only. Someone who is used to no spaces would have an easier time reading it with no spaces, because that's what they're more used to. In either case, you're correct that it's a bad recommendation.

Comment: Itendtothinkspaceshelpreadabilityingeneral.Letpeopleusewhitespacethewaytheywant.ThisisprobablythebiggestthingthatbugsmeaboutPython

Answer (score 7):

Alsways be careful when programmatically logging users in, you might get the error ´`user has no attribute "backend"`. You have to set the backend too if that has no happened previously. [Project that uses this](https://github.com/arpheno/eestecnet/blob/master/apps/account/views.py#L50) and some sample code:

```
def splash_register(request):
  if request.session.get('beta'):

    if request.method=='POST':
        userform=MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if userform.is_valid():
            #username of <30 char is required by Django User model.  I'm storing username as a hash of user email 

            user=userform.save(commit=False)
            user.username=hash(user.email)
            user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
            user.save()


            username=user.username
            password=str(userform.cleaned_data['password'])
            auth.login(request, user)
            request.session['first_visit']=True
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            userform=MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
            return render_to_response("website/splash_register.html", {'userform':userform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response("website/splash_register.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))     
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/splash/')
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer definitely works but, I prefer to use the Django built in auth forms, like `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`

Here is a snippet that shows the important part

```
form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    try:
        form.clean()
    except ValidationError:
        # handle error

    login(request, form.get_user())
```

The major difference in this approach is that `AuthenticationForm.clean` method calls `authentication` function for you and checks `User.is_active` for you as well.